# NoMethodError when I push a object into a Doc with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm having this problem, I tried a lot of differents aproachs but 
everytime it falls in that error.

**Enviroment:**

Rails 3.0.5

Mongoid 2.0.1

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document 

 field :name 

 has_and_belongs_to_many :companies 
end 

class Company 
 include Mongoid::Document 

 field :name 

 has_and_belongs_to_many :users 
end
```

In my UserController method Create a I do something like this:

```
@user = User.where(:email => params[:user][:email]) 
 if @user.count > 0 
  @user.companies.push(@company) 
  @user.save 
  @company.users.push(@user) 
  @company.save 
 else 
  @user = User.create(:name => params[:user][:name], 
                      :email => params[:user][:email], 
                      :password => "123456") 

  @user.companies.push(@company) 
  @user.save 
  @company.users.push(@user) 
  @company.save 
 end
```

When the user dont exist works great.

But if the user is already in the DB, fall a error.

```
NoMethodError in UserController#create 
undefined method `companies' for #<Array:0x10679f638>
```

But after all it pushes the object into the document.

I don't know if I'm missing something.

If someone know how to solve this ... will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `User.where` returns an array, which is assigned to `@user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@user = User.where(:email => params[:user][:email]).first
```

On a side note, you may also want to push some of this code into one of your models, either the User or Company model, so that in your controller you would only have one call such as:

```
@company.add_user(@user)
```

The implementation details of adding a user would then be encapsulated in your model.

You may also want to consider embedding the two calls to ActiveRecord::Base#save into a single transaction to avoid ending up with inconsistent data in your database.

Comment: Thanks man. It works fine.

Now I can refactor all this code.